# What merchant has the most gold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Who can I sell to that has boatloads of cash?

Ideally they'll be easily accessible by fast travel and will buy the most different types of items, but a rich type-specific merchant will work too.

Comment: I miss Creeper.

Comment: I've been searching for this person, too.

Comment: It's all about Creeper and the merchant mudcrab.  I smell a mod coming...

Comment: I did randomly find this guy out in the wild at a Stormcloak encampment who had 1280 or something. That's the most I've seen. Can't remember exactly where though :/

Comment: To anyone who can find an easily accessible wealthy merchant, there's some instant bounty in it for you.  Figure it could take a while, though...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you complete the [restore the Thieves Guild to its former glory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/how-do-i-restore-the-glory-of-the-thieves-guild) quests, all the fences will have 4000 gold to barter with.  You can further boost this via investing and the speech perk for a total of 5500 per fence.

Comment: is that before or after the perks?

Comment: @Sean, does that mean getting rid of the skeleton key as well?

Comment: Not just the fence in the HQ; you can get some fences in other cities up to 4k gold by doing Thieves Guild quests. @Tyler just get in the habit of buying every lockpick you see and you'll never run out.

Comment: @yx. That's 4000 not including 1000 from the 100 Speech perk -- so 5000 total with the perk.

Comment: I completed the quests (returned the skeleton key) but the fence in HQ(rat cave are) has only 1000. :-???

Comment: @VaibhavGarg the quests you need to complete are the ones that [restore the thieves guild to its former glory](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/how-do-i-restore-the-glory-of-the-thieves-guild).  At that point all the fences seems to have 4000 gold and up to 5500 if you invest and have the speech perk.  I haven't done any of the thieves guild story quests quests, only the random + glory ones and my fences all have 4k gold.

Comment: This requires a substantial time investment just to be able to sell a bunch of junk - I get that it's probably the easiest option someone's found so far, but I'm holding out.

Comment: You also get a bunch of merchants in the Cistern you can sell to.

Comment: Fences cannot be invested in.

Answer (score 8):

There is a guy at the Riverwood trader who has 10000 gold once you invest with him.  I don't know if it's a glitch.  This was on the Xbox before the first update so it could be fixed.

Comment: This has since been patched. He now has a normal amount of gold for a general goods merchant(1250 with investment, 2250 with master trader).

Answer (score 5):

Selling things in Riften is good, especially if you are part of the Thieves Guild. Then you'll have 5 merchants to sell things to. 3 in the market, 1 smith and Tonilia in the Ragged Flagon.

Comment: Two general traders in the market, the smith, the alchemist, the general store in the gray quarter makes 5, plus the Ragged Flagon.

Comment: Sadri's Used Wares(the grey quarter) is in Windhelm.

Answer (score 5):

I found this because I had the same question, and after reading the available answers, I can offer a trick that might still help.

Sell as much as you can/want to a merchant, then SAVE the game.  Then, kill that merchant.  Once they're dead, simply reload the save you created before killing them.  Their inventory and gold will be restocked.  Just keep doing this until you've sold all you want to sell.

I know this doesn't answer the question specifically, but I still thought it might be helpful.

Comment: Is killing necessary?

Comment: @GmNoob It is not necessary if you restart the game -- restarting the game resets their available gold without killing them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a full save, just quicksave then aggro the merchant [killing optional] and when you quickload they should have more gold.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the Dremora Merchant, obtainable in one of the Black Book quests on Solstheim, from the Dragonborn DLC. He only has 2,000 starting gold, but you can summon him from anywhere in as little as a single keypress. His gold reserve is (usually) replenished every 24 hours, so you can sell, wait 24 hours, and sell again ad infinitum. All this without even stepping away from the bandit corpse you just looted. Instant liquidation, anywhere, anytime.

Bonus: he is also guaranteed to be carrying weapons on your level. No more rummaging through haystacks of iron daggers to find that Dremora Longsword you wanted.

Comment: As a helpful tip. The Dremora Merchants money also resets when you save the game and log out. So if you don't mind a lot of logging in/out, this one merchant can provide pretty handy infinite money.

Comment: The Dremora Merchant, similar to Enthir, is immune to certain effects regarding barter. They generally have much worse prices than pretty much all other merchants.