# How do I restore the glory of the Thieves Guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

One of the achievements for the Thieves Guild says "Restore the Thieves Guild to its former glory."

Brynjolf doesn't say anything to me, I can't seem to find Karliah, and as far as I can tell, I am finished with the plotline quests for the Thieves Guild. All I have left available are repeatable quests from Vex and Delvin.

How can I get this achievement?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First, complete the Thieves Guild quest line (ends with you returning the Skeleton Key).

Then you need to do Delvin and Vex's generic (radiant) jobs until you have done five (5) radiant quests for each of these cities:

- Markarth
- Windhelm
- Solitude
- Whiterun

It doesn't matter which kind of jobs you do for them. After you have completed five jobs in one city area, you will receive a special quest from Delvin for that area. Complete that quest to "upgrade" the Thieves Guild to a higher restoration status. Riften quests *do not count*. I would advise abandoning the Riften jobs unless you just want easy money. After you complete five jobs for one city, further jobs in that city won't progress the restoration. To make sure you only get jobs for cities you need, you can take a job from Vex/Delvin; then quicksave after you've ended dialogue with them, but before the job itself appears.  If the job that you are given is for a city you do not need, simply load the quicksave and a new radiant quest will be assigned for you.  This is easier and more efficient than simply abandoning quests, which also has been known to affect your "quests completed" count in the game.

In summary: 5 radiant quests for each city, and 4 special quests, one for each city, for a total of 24 quests.

Comment: Do the five radiant quests have to be different types of quests, or can you just do a lot of one single type of quest? Can I, in theory, fulfill the radiant quest requirement by just doing five numbers jobs in each city?

Comment: You can do five of the same type of job. I prefer numbers jobs because, for me, they were the fastest to complete.

Answer (score 4):

Listen to this video. It explains everything! It helped me A LOT.

What you need to do is complete Delvin and Vex's jobs for 4 towns, which are:

- Solitude
- Markarth
- Whiterun
- Windhelm

After doing 5 jobs for one city, you get a special job. There are 4 special jobs for each of the 4 holds above. After doing 4 special jobs, talk to Brynjolf to start [Under new Management](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Under_New_Management). Complete it, and you're done!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Frank I edited that answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

pretty much right as soon as you join the theives guild do the missions Vex/Delvin's jobs 5 times in one city. then as you do that you will notice changes around the bar. if you finish the story line then you cant restore the thieves guild to its former glory. so when you join do the side missions from vex/delvin and the do the story
. hope this help.

Comment: I finished the main questline, and the guild is still being able to be restored, its got the weapons dealer so far, so i dont know if there was a patch or something, but you can restore the guild.