# What are the benefits of doing the radiant quests from the thieves guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have done several dozens of the radiant quests from Vex and Delvin and earned a lot of money doing this. Beside the coin, does it make sense to do those quests?

In the beginning I thought that doing them will enable the special quests to retake certain cities, but after I while it felt more like those special quests become available as I level up.

How do those radiant quests really work? Do the influence other plot lines or are they just cheap fillers to get some money?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The special quest for a particular city is unlocked after you've done 5 radiant quests in that city.  When you complete a special job in the city, you get one (or more) of these benefits:

1. Increase the amount of money available to all fences in the game.
2. Some of those quests add an additional thieves guild fence to that area.
3. Add another merchant (not a fence) to the Ragged Flagon (guaranteed).

Also, you will need to complete all these special quests before you are given the chance to become the guild master, which has its own set of benefits.

Comment: Ya know yx, you may have all the answers but I am starting to wonder how much of your rep is from me :)

Answer (score 1):

When you complete 5 quests in a specific city, Delvin will give you a quest specific to that city. For each one you complete, a new shop will open up in the Ratworks.

You must complete all 4 city-specific quests to finish the thieves guild.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/how-do-i-restore-the-glory-of-the-thieves-guild) is strongly related, and more specific information can be found there.

Answer (score 1):

> After performing five total Small Jobs in a city, Delvin will offer
>   that city's special job. It may be less time-consuimg to quit jobs in
>   cities in which you have already completed the Special Job. In order
>   to restore the Thieves' Guild to its former glory and assume the title
>   of Guildmaster, you must perform these four special jobs.

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_(Skyrim)#Special_Jobs