# How can I find out which special thieves guild quests I have completed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

According to this [question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/how-do-i-restore-the-glory-of-the-thieves-guild), I need to complete a special quest in Markarth, Windhelm, Solitude and Whiterun.

Unfortunately I didn't know this when I started the thieves guild career path and now I do not remember which of those quests are done and which are still open. I completed 2 or 3 oh those, but not all of them.

Is there an easy way to find this information? Maybe someone can post the quest names and the city associated with it. I can look up those quests in my quest log to identify completed quests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, you can tell how many you've done by looking around the Ragged Flagon; each quest adds a merchant to a stall. So if you count the merchants, aside from Tonilia, that should let you know the count.

The quests are:

[Silver Lining](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Silver_Lining) (Markarth) - `TGTQ01`
Clear out [Pinewatch](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Pinewatch) of bandits and retrieve a mold. [Endon](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Endon) will also become a fence.

[The Dainty Sload](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Dainty_Sload) (Solitude) - `TGTQ02`
Plant drugs on a ship captain.

[Imitation Amnesty](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Imitation_Amnesty) (Whiterun) - `TGTQ03`
Help remove records of a prisoner held in Dragonsreach before he's fingered for a murder in Solitude.

[Summerset Shadows](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Summerset_Shadows) (Windhelm) - `TGTQ04`
Exact revenge for a murder committed by an upstart thievery ring holed up in [Uttering Hills Cave](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Uttering_Hills_Cave). [Niranye](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Niranye) becomes a fence and can now buy anything.

If you have the PC version, you can check the status of those quest IDs above using something like `GetStage TGTQ01`.

Comment: You can also check your quest log for completed quests with these quest names. Then you can focus on doing side jobs in only the places you haven't already done a special job instead of place you have.