# Thieves guild: How to find out which cities still need special jobs

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

This is somewhat related to this question: [How can I find out which special thieves guild quests I have completed?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48621/how-can-i-find-out-which-special-thieves-guild-quests-i-have-completed), but I'm not yet that far and still doing the extra job quests for Vex and the other guy Delvin.

Is there a simple way to get the count of done extra job (radiant)  quests per city to see where to concentrate on to get the special job for that city?

I play on xbox, so no console available.

Comment: its probably easier to look for the specific special quests in your quest completed log to see which one's you've done already.

Comment: I found that trying different jobs and not always the same one tends to often switch cities. Considering the fact that you have 5 to do in each city, worst case scenario is you'll do 40 quests before having done 5 in each (or 20 total)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember reading on one of the wiki sites that there isn't a means to track it.  You have to take notes on what you've done in the 4 holds.

Comment: okay. Not the answer i was looking for, but well, then I have to live with that. Then I need to start tracking now and will have me surprised with the special jobs. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You can just look in the completed quests. Also, if you exit out of the conversation after you've accepted the quest and save when the quest pops up if you've already done the quest in that city. Just reload and it should change.

Answer (score 0):

In all honesty, it doesn't matter. Just keep doing jobs until you get a special quest. Save before you talk to Delvin or Vex about new jobs and make sure they give you a job in a different city than one in which you've already done the special quest. Reload otherwise. You can also reload if Delvin and Vex give you the same city, and that way you don't accidentally do 6 when you only needed to do 5. In other words, there's not much of a benefit to keeping track.

You will be notified immediately the next time you talk to Delvin that there's a special quest in the city, so it's not like you have to wait several game days doing unnecessary quests.

(Side note: If you had the PC, you could try `help TGTQ01 0` through `help TGTQ04` and see if there are any variables counting the quests you've done toward them. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader since it doesn't apply to the OP.)

Answer (score 0):

The cities are:

Windhelm
Whiterun
Markarth
Solitude

Note: Some of you might encountered doing riften hold jobs instead of solitude or windhelm jobs. this is because you probally not finished the thieves guild questline or you didn't participate in the civil war's win.

You will do jobs for each hold. There are unlimited amount of jobs. Once you've done a few, you will get a special job for each hold.