# Quitting Thieves Guild Quests

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After you join the Thieves Guild, are there any consequences for quitting a job you get from either Vex or Delvin?

I recall Delvin saying something along the lines of:

> You keep quitting these jobs, and I might stop assigning them to you.

Is that true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are no consequences - they are just commenting and there's no bite to their bark.

If you want to complete all the side quests and '[Return the Thieves Guild to its Former Glory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38891/how-do-i-restore-the-glory-of-the-thieves-guild)', quitting jobs in cities you've done the special quest in is the only sensible way way to do so, or you'll be there for a *long* time.

Comment: I should add a screenshot of my game with pages of these failed quests.

Answer (score 2):

That's certainly untrue. I quit for another job whenever I got an assignment in Markarth.

Comment: @downvoter: what? why? this is correct...

Comment: It doesn't explain very well, is probably why.

Answer (score 0):

The thieves guild quests are what's called "radiant" quests, and there's basically no limit to them and they never run out. You can quit as many as you want to with no bad results.

Comment: Just being Radiant quests doesn't mean that it's impossible to disqualify yourself from getting more of certain ones. It's possible for the Radiant system to track quest failures and use that as part of the decision logic for (not) triggering future Radiant quests. Thieves Guild quests just don't *happen* to be written that way, is all, but they as easily could have been.

Answer (score 0):

You can quick jobs if you can't try to complete them. Sometimes doing some quests breaks the Thieves Guild jobs for example:

> Because you did the quest Battle for Whiterun, Heimskr's house will be covered in rubble and there are jobs that have to do with this. If this happens, quit the job and do another. You gte unlimited jobs until you complete the 4 special jobs.

But don't worry, there are no consequences since there are unlimited jobs.

Comment: Just to clarify, where is that excerpt taken from?