# Shops with lots of Money in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What merchant has the most gold?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36593/what-merchant-has-the-most-gold)

I need to find some shops to unload my Potions from Alchemy at.

The Alchemy shops don't have much money.  Are there any other shops that have a good amount of money that will take potions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a part of the thieves guild then all of the fences you receive will have 4000 gold by the time you finish all the quests

> You need to actually become Guild leader, not just finish the main thieves guild quest line.

Alternatively you can buy the speech perk "Master Trader" at 100 speech skill which will give every merchant an extra 1000 gold.

Comment: will these "stack"? e.g. 5000g?

Comment: @MorganTiley I'll have to check when I get back on Skyrim, as I haven't been to any of my fences yet since buying the perk.